# HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible screen flickering with ubuntu 14.04,15.10 and 16

Tags: hp

My HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible laptop is flickering continuously after booting. I purchased it with a pre-installed windows 10 but immediately uninstalled it for ubuntu 15.10. Everything else works fine except the screen flickering issue. I have tried nomodeset, changing resolutions, booting between uefi and legacy mode, different ubuntu versions (14,15,16), upgraded kernel to 4.5.0,set tear free option to both true and false in /etc/X11/xorg.conf file, using processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs, sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade but apparently none of these options seem to work. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestions over at the forums:

[Updated Nvidia Drivers - Resulted in Flickering Display](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243912)

Try these and let me know if it works.

Comment: William had forgotten to mention that I tried the compizconfig-settings-manager then checked "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint" still didn't work.